# ASP.NET Identity Core 2: add custom claim based on login URL

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I've got an ASP.NET core application which implements a custom UserClaimsPrincipalFactory , including the following method:

```
protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(TUser user)
```

This works well. I can check attributes of the user and include claims dynamically.

But I'd like to add a separate "admin" login endpoint, so that users can decide if they'd rather have the admin experience when they log in. Can I pass additional information about the current session (such as the login URL or any form parameters) to the GenerateClaimsAsync method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessing request information from `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`, you could register `IHttpContextAccessor` like below:

```
    public class CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser> : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser> where TUser : class
{
    private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;
    public CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(UserManager<TUser> userManager
        , IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor
        ,IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) 
        : base(userManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }
    protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(TUser user)
    {
        var ci = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
        ci.AddClaim(new Claim("RequestPath", _httpContext.Request.Path.Value));
        return ci;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you!